# If my subquery is returning multiple value then i need to perform normalization?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT Title 
FROM movie 
WHERE Movie_no = (SELECT Movie_no 
                  FROM Customer 
                  INNER JOIN issues ON customer.`Cus_id`=issues.`Cus_id`
                  WHERE NAME = 'Shyam')
```

Comment: just sounds like your customer has many issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  You just need to use `IN` or `ANY`:

```
SELECT Title
FROM movie
WHERE Movie_no IN (SELECT Movie_no
                   FROM Customer INNER JOIN
                        issues
                        ON customer.Cus_id = issues.Cus_id
                   WHERE NAME = 'Shyam'
                  );
```

I mean, you might need to normalize your data for other reasons, but a subquery returning more than one value would not be such a reason.  And, your data structure seems reasonable, based on this one query.